# How to separate host list and group hiererachy in ansible's inventory?

Tags: ansible, hierarchy, ansible-inventory

I have a big project under Ansible. There are many groups in it, most of them for the sake of clarity. For example, there are groups 'dbaccess', 'java', etc, which help to find hosts which need access to database, to have java installed, etc. Some of them nested (f.e. 'collector' group is a child for 'java' group, as all collectors need java).

It all is kept inside inventory using 'group:children' technique.

But when I want to create staging inventory I have a problem: I need not only provide new hosts in inventory, but also recreate whole group hierarchy.

I wonder if there are any way to separate inventory in such a way that group hierarchy would be kept separate from host list?

Or, may be, there is some other way to organize such hierarchy in Ansible?

(example of my real inventory):

```
[collectors]
(host list)
[publishers-http]
(host list)
[publishers-smtp]
(host list)
[central]
(host list)

[java:children]
collectors
publishers-http
central

[postgre_access:children]
collectors
publishers
central

[mongo_access:children]
collectors
publishers-smtp
central

[redis_access:children]
central
publishers
```

I want a way to change host lists for staging but keep relations between groups intact.

Comment: I want to have 'staging' inventory without copying all hierarchy information from 'production'. Ansible do not allow two inventories at the same time, so I can't just split it to 'hosts' and 'group relationships' files.

Comment: "*Ansible do not allow two inventories at the same time*" -- I said "save to two files" in the same inventory. "*I can't just split it to 'hosts' and 'group relationships' files.*" -- of course you can. You just need to make sure the file for groups is read after the file for hosts. Thus `groups` and `hosts` names won't work, but `01_hosts`, `02_groups` will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your inventory into two files -- one named `01_hosts` containing:

```
[collectors]
(host list)
[publishers-http]
(host list)
[publishers-smtp]
(host list)
[central]
(host list)
```

the other named `02_groups` containing:

```
[java:children]
collectors
publishers-http
central

[postgre_access:children]
collectors
publishers
central

[mongo_access:children]
collectors
publishers-smtp
central

[redis_access:children]
central
publishers
```

Save them to `my_inventory` directory, use path to `my_inventory` as a parameter for the inventory (either in CLI, or in `ansible.cfg`).

Use symlinks to have a single source for `02_groups`.

---

I suggested `01_` and `02_` prefixes because Ansible reads files from an inventory directory alphabetically and hosts/groups must be defined before groups of groups.

Comment: I missed the part where they said that inventory may be a directory. And symlink idea is neat! Thank you!